# make *** No rule to make target in Makefile

Tags: make

I have problem what makefile does not excute with including file.

My Makefile is made like this.

```
SHELL = /bin/csh
CURDIR = $(shell pwd)
....
....
include $(CURDIR)/device.cfg

....
```

Done.  Also exactly the device.cfg file exist in there.

But when i have typed 'make' then the error message what make : *** No rule to make target 'xxxxx/device.cfg : No such file or directory happen.

How can I solve this problem?

I am using RHR5.0.